# C2 compiler for Java SE Embedded 8

Tags: java, embedded, armv7

I created a JRE for our IMX6 (ARMv7) platform using [JRECreate tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/jrecreate.htm). The tool is targeting ARMv6. So, as I understand the JRE support ARMv6.

Now, I did some research and found out that c2 compiler require ARMv7.

The question is, if we build the app with C2, will it work when it is started with this JRE?

Comment: Why not try yourself and run a testsuite? No one here will warrant it will work.

Comment: I try my best to make sure if it will work or not, prior to requesting the java team to recompile with C2

Comment: I did not say to recompile _your_ code. You do know what a compliance test-suite is, I presume.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure, coming from C++ background. I though testing would require recompilation with the new optimizations flags to see if jar compiled with C2 will work, isn't it?

Comment: That is not different for any other languge. To verify a toolchain u use a test suite. Not sure which that would be for java, but there has to be one for sure.